# Can't change font in Numbering Style - Office Word

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

In word document when I use the numbering format for my text, the font can not be changed at all.

The size will be changed, but the font is always Calibri and If I change the font, the name of the font will change but the style of it won't!

Where is the problem?

Office version is 2019 and here is a sample in the Persian language:

http://fs2.filegir.com/cuttlas/Test.zip

**Updated:**

the font can be changed to some other fonts, but most of the fonts will not work.
Where is the difference here? why some fonts will be applied and so many other ones will not?

**Update TWO:**

when the numbering format contains a `)` sign the font will change very easily.
but when the numbering format contains `.` or any other character (or even empty) it will not change :(

Comment: Check to see if the style is Paragraph only. I think it needs to be Linked Paragraph and Character for the font to apply. This is one of the maddening things about Word styles and numbering styles. Also, It's best to say what version of Word, what type of numbering, etc.

Comment: Posting an example document would help to analyze the issue.

Comment: updated the question my friends

Comment: Change the font for numbering in the Numbering Dialog. Generally, for best results, set your numbering up in the Define New Multi-Level List dialog with each level attached to a different paragraph style. Here are two articles about this: Windows: http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html  and Mac: http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/   You can set the font for each level in the list in that document. This will control the font and size of the Number / Bullet, not the text that follows.

Comment: @user8356 No, it does not need to be a linked style! It should be a numbering list which is linked to paragraph styles. There is a difference.

Comment: has updated the question again.

Answer (score 3):

See my comment for links.

Ideally, you will set up your numbering using the Define New Multi-Level List dialog with each level attached to an existing paragraph style. If you do not want to do that but want a simple list, you can use the Define New Number List dialog.

**In either of these, you can set the font for the Numbering / Bullet.**

[image: Define New Numbering List Dialog]

[image: Define New Multi-Level List Dialog]

Again, see the links in my comment for directions on how to set up numbering linked to styles. This is the only known way to have numbering that can survive editing by multiple people.

You are using a "simple" list which is fine for "simple" documents that you won't be editing much. For important documents, use a multi-level list, with each level linked to a paragraph style. You apply the numbering, not through the numbering commands, but by applying the appropriate style. This is virtually bullet-proof.

Comment: has updated the question again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem exactly with Persian **B Nazanin** font. I changed the **New Times Roman** font to **B Nazanin** but still, it was showing as **New Times Roman**.
Fix(For me it was working fine):
Please go to **Define New Multilevel List**:
[image]
Add extra space to **Enter Formatting for number**.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Please Enter the "SPACE" Character after numbers or after "-". look like this:
"3-2- "

by this solution number's font set to your font (B Nazanin).

Goodlock bro.